# How to implement vertical column in a grid? ExtJS 6

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I need to implement in a grid without using `data:[ ]`, so it has the same parameters as the horizontal header in the table (text, static, sortable, fixed, etc.).

[image]

There is a Pivot package, which provides such an opportunity, but unfortunately, I can't use it.

Is there an alternative way to create a vertical column in a grid?

P.S.: Treelist is also not an option.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: As I wrote, I tried to use 'data:[ ]' and dataIndex, but in there future I will get the necessary data from Database, so I can't use both sources. If I use the treelist model, the values for  these column should come also from the database, but this is not rationally, because the values will always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

> I hope this will help you! (it is an independant solution, not a part of extJs)

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.column1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 2px;
}

.column2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}
.column3 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span class="column1">1</span>
<span class="column1">2</span>
<span class="column1">3</span>
<span class="column1">4</span>
<span class="column2">5</span>
<span class="column2">6</span>
<span class="column2">7</span>
<span class="column3">8</span>
<span class="column3">9</span>
<span class="column3">10</span>
</body>
</html>
```